# Behat, Selenium2 in new window (Facebook) cookies are disabled

Tags: facebook, selenium, cookies

I am using Behat3 with Selenium2 (locally).
Today I want to write a Behat-Test for our Facebook-Login.

My test looks like this:

```gherkin
Background:
   Given I am on the home page

Scenario: Test button in account dropdown
   When I hover the account dropdown
   And I click on ".login .facebook"
   And I wait for 5 seconds

   Then there should be 2 open windows

Scenario: Test facebook login
   Given I hovered the account dropdown
   And I click on ".login .facebook"
   And I wait for 5 seconds

   When I focus the opened window
   And I fill in the following:
     | email   | facebooklogin@mail.de |
     | pass    | facebookpassword      |
   And I submit the "#login_form" form
```

Everything works fine. Except, that I cannot make a login on the Facebook auth page. Facebook says: `Cookies are disabled, please activate cookies to sign in`.

So, I added a "I wait for 60 seconds" at the end of my scenario and I had checked the browser-settings. I expected, that the option "Allow cookies" is disabled. But it's **enabled**!

Here is my question:
Is there a way, to tell selenium, that cookies should be enabled in the new window or why said Facebook that cookies are disabled, although they are enabled?

To open the new window, I try something like that:

```php
$windows = $this->getSession()->getDriver()->getWindowNames();
$windowName = $windows[count($windows)-1];
$this->getSession()->getDriver()->switchToWindow($windowName);
```

But I have also tried something like `getSession(sessionName)->switchToWindow` and some more possibilities...

Can anyone help?

Regards, Tim

Comment: You are aware that scraping Facebook is not allowed: https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php

Comment: Oh. The message about Cookies is very confusing. Thank you. I'll try to apply, to get these permissions.

Comment: _“I'll try to apply, to get these permissions”_ – that will be a pretty pointless endeavor, presumably …

Comment: Why are you scraping Facebook?